# Debugging applications in Visual Studio on Remote Desktop causes the session to freeze

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, visual-studio

Running Visual Studio 2003 on Windows Server 2003 (not configured as a terminal server), most of the time that I try to use the debugger, I completely lose control of the session. I end up having to log in to another open session and kill devenv.exe before I can recover.  This is usually on winforms apps, not web sites or console apps.

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Are you connecting normally or to the console session? (using /console or /admin switch)

Comment: Does not make a difference, we connect usually without /console but sometimes we use it (if there are no sessions left).

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this behaviour as well, but my problem came from:

> highlighting text, and moving it with the mouse + left button click

The RD session would freeze for about 2 minutes. I would silently sit in my pool of WTF for that time, and then proceed to forget about the issue. About 2 minutes later, bam, same problem, same cause.